# Is there a way I can use Google Cloud IAM for authorization access on my web app?

Tags: web-applications, authorization, identity-management

I'm looking for a way to restrict use on my web app by requiring users to login and granting access based on membership to some list.

The functionality would be like sharing a Google Doc with a person and they're part of a member of a Google Group, they can have view/edit/etc access to the Google Doc.  I'm trying to do the same with but instead of a Google Doc, it's my web app.

Is there a way to to do this by adding a person to a Google Group and using the Google IAM to grant access if included in a Google Group?  I know you can use the Google Cloud IAM for *authentication* but I want to include *authorization*.

I'm also a small-time developer and not some large company so I'd like to avoid solutions that require large-scale authorization since I figure those sort of things exist for larger companies.

I've looked on the Google Cloud documentation and articles but mostly I find authentication examples:

- https://support.google.com/a/answer/167097?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

Comment: Did you try OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications > https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow 
or else Asgardeo (https://wso2.com/asgardeo/) provides a simple way to add authz using groups

Comment: @SuvinNimnakaSukka Yes I considered Oauth but from what I read including your link, that this would before a user to authorize the application to use the user's specific resources like Sheets, etc.  But I have an app which will access resources which do not belong to a user.  Maybe I'm just not understanding Oauth?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for authorization, maybe you can use [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview).

When an application or resource is protected by IAP, it can only be accessed through the proxy by principals, also known as users, who have the correct Identity and Access Management (IAM) role. You can create a group and give the group the needed IAM role.